# Why is Jquery hide and js style.display="none" not interchangeable

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a simple Slider Effect below, but I have some question with it:

> it's work

```
$(function () {
    var slideIndex = 1;
    SliderShow(slideIndex);

    function plusIndex(n) {
        SliderShow(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function SliderShow(n) {
        var Slider = $('.Slider');
        var SliderItem = Slider.children('li');
        if (n > SliderItem.length) {
            slideIndex = 1;
        }
        if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = SliderItem.length;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < SliderItem.length; i++) {
            SliderItem[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        SliderItem[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    }

    $('.prevBtn').click(function () {
        plusIndex(-1);
    });

    $('.nextBtn').click(function () {
        plusIndex(+1);
    });
});
```

but when I change `SliderItem[i].style.display = "none"` to `SliderItem[i].hide()` the slide was broken, what's wrong with it?

There is any different between Jquery hide and js style?
Did I misunderstand sometihing?

Comment: One thing about .hide() opposed to simply setting the style to display:none. The .hide() method uses the display:none style rule - but also adds an !important;  to the end - therefore there is an actualy difference in the styling between using .hide() and manually stetting the display to none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this `SliderItem[slideIndex-1]` returns a native DOM element which does not have a `hide` method, you need to wrap it with jQuery function `$`:

```
$(SliderItem[slideIndex-1]).hide();
```

Comment: *...returns a native DOM element **which does not have a `hide` method***.

Comment: Oh, I see!!  Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question "**difference between jquery hide and js style**"

The behaviour of these two are most likely the same except for one thing.

By using `SliderItem[i].style.display = "none"`
You are only changing the style `display` to `none`

While JQuery `.hide()` does an extra stuff which is saving the previous value of display property to cache so you can get back to it later when you use `.show()`.

You may check this [link](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) as reference.